# Push() not working when called from inside getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, getjson

I'm currently using the jQuery drag and drop [formbuilder plugin](https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder). Now, I want to fetch drag and drop elements from my database and add those element to my drag and drop builder.

This is my request function:

```
function getElements(){
    $.getJSON( getContextPath() + "/api/elements/get", function (data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            addElement();
        });
    });
}
```

Now, I want to add them to the formbuilder instance (I use [this](http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formBuilder/control-plugins/) example and I use some pre-defined values):

```
function addElement(){
    if (!window.fbControls) window.fbControls = [];
    window.fbControls.push(function(controlClass) {
        console.log("HERE");
        class controlStarRating extends controlClass {

            static get definition() {
              return {
                icon: '',
                i18n: {
                  default: 'Star Rating'
                }
              };
            }

            configure() {
                this.js = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.js';
                this.css = '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rateYo/2.2.0/jquery.rateyo.min.css';
            }

            build() {
              return this.markup('span', null, {id: this.config.name});
            }

            onRender() {
              let value = this.config.value || 3.6;
              $('#'+this.config.name).rateYo({rating: value});
            }
        }

      // register control
      controlClass.register('starRating', controlStarRating);
      return controlStarRating;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, my `console.log("HERE")` is not called, so it seems like it alle stops there. The weird thing is, if I use this as my request function the function is properly executed:

```
function getElements(){
    var allElementsData = ["test"];
    // $.getJSON( getContextPath() + "/api/template/get", function (data){
    // });
    $.each(allElementsData, function(key, val) {
        addElement();
    });
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I assume the issue is in the returned value from **/api/elements/get**. Can you add the **data** value?  Is it an array, or a json object?

Comment: No, I don't even use the returned data value yet... I use the code with some hardcoded default values.

Comment: I'm sorry, but inside **$.getJSON** you use: **$.each(data, func**. Isn't it

Answer (score 0):

In the function addElement you are pushing another function into the array window.fbControls. But that second function is only placed in the array not executed. You could for example execute it with this statement: `window.fbControls[0]()`. Then you would see the `console.log("HERE")`

Comment: What do you mean with that? That is not working either unfortunately. Also, why is it working in the second `getElements()` function but not in the first one?

Comment: Ok. I don't see where the function is called that you add to the array. But as it is working the second time, the only reason I can think of, that it isn't working with the $.getJSON, would be that /api/elements/get perhaps returns an ```[]``` (an empty array) as the data. Then the function would be called 0 times. Have you inspected the network data (in the developer tools of your browser) for the call to /api/elements/get?